# Cannot get create-react-app to work

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, create-react-app

I am trying to get create-react-app to work. Originally I had a React app working but decided to make it ES6+ syntax over ES5, which exploded on me. After several hours of debugging I decided to start over and deleted everything.

I am working on a server, not locally (if that makes a difference.) The first time I set up React I followed  https://tylermcginnis.com/react-js-tutorial-1-5-utilizing-webpack-and-babel-to-build-a-react-js-app/ and got something working but when I stumbled on https://egghead.io/lessons/react-react-fundamentals-development-environment-setup and decided to try create-react-app

I followed the instructions (ran `npm create-react-app i -g` then `create-react-app my-app`. When I cd’d in, I found only a barebones package.json file… I thought I was supposed to get essentially a starter structure no config needed... but it only creates the folder and the package.json file. I have been googling hard but cannot seem to find someone with a similar problem. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Unless I misunderstood, the point of create-react-app was to avoid having to tinker with webpack.config.json, babel.rc, or setting up from scratch the package.json. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out the issue was my digital ocean droplet did not have enough ram to process the command in question. I solved the issue by creating a swapfile on my server (1024mb) and that solved the issue. My server only had 512mb ram which I guess was not enough. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-change-swap-size-on-ubuntu-14-04 is the guide I followed, hope this helps somebody down the road.

Answer (score 0):

`create-react-app` uses a package called `react-scripts` as its backbone. When you create an app using `create-react-app`, you get all the functionality that `react-scripts` provides you, including the following scripts:

```
npm run start
npm run build
npm run test
npm run eject
```

All of the actual configuration and dependencies are intentionally hidden to keep things simple. If you would like to see the full configuration of the app, you can use `npm run eject` to eject the abstraction of the app and get all the actual files and config it's using so you can make modifications of your own. Keep in mind, once you run `npm run eject`, you can't go back to this simpler format (unless you recreate the app).

Comment: I tried to run create-react-app react-app.. it didn't return any error but again just made the folder 'react-app' and an unconfigured packag.json file. 

``Creating a new React app in /var/www/html/react-app.``

``Installing packages. This might take a couple minutes.
Installing react-scripts...``

``npm install --save-dev --save-exact react-scripts failed uri https://registry.npmjs.org/istanbul`` was all the console gave me.

Comment: This means that your connection failed and packages didn't get installed. Try again with a stable network connection.

Comment: We need to add more graceful error handling so that you don't end up with a single file. But in this case it's just npm failing and it's likely because of a network issue.

Comment: Dan Abramov I figured this may be the case but I am not sure what would cause it, I have installed other NPM packages just fine (infact I *had* everything working before I went and broke it). The server is a Digital Ocean Droplet, any history with those having issues? Would love to get this working. I am new to a lot of this (node, NPM, babel, etc) so part of it is me not knowing *how* to fully troubleshoot.